# Sodium metal from electrolysis of molten sodium bisulfate?

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox, electrolysis

My question is relatively straightforward. Can sodium metal be extracted from molten sodium bisulfate via electrolysis?

I have done it before with molten sodium hydroxide, but there is such a small temperature range to keep the salt molten and prevent the extracted sodium from dissolving back into the melt.

I then find out that sodium bisulfate melts at a much lower temperature than sodium hydroxide. This gives me much more wiggle room for error.

Comment: Metallic sodium reacts with molten sodium bisulfate to produce hydrogen gas, according to : $\ce{2 Na + 2 NaHSO_4 -> H_2 + 2 Na_2SO_4}$. So you will get $\ce{H_2}$  instead of $\ce{Na}$.

Comment: The melting point of anhydrous $\ce{NaHSO4}$ is $\pu{315 ^\circ C}$. But, it decomposes to $\ce{Na2S2O7 + H2O}$ at  $\pu{315 ^\circ C}$ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bisulfate)).

Comment: You may use $\ce{NaNO2}$, which melts at $\pu{271 ^\circ C}$. Keep the bath below  $\pu{300 ^\circ C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem: The sulfur(VI) is also reducible. Assuming you actually use the dehydration product $\ce{Na2S2O7}$ (liquid range [$401-460°\mathrm{C}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_pyrosulfate)) which would avoid the possibility of hydrogen reduction, your cathodic reaction could produce sulfur dioxide or sulfite ion ($\ce{S(VI)->S(IV)}$) instead of sodium metal. Halides, which are not reducible, make for a more predictable cathodic reduction reaction.